# ajax call to send post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a small function that will eventually save to a database, but um having trouble reading the post into the php, here is the jquery:

```
$("#loginbtn").click(function() {

        var myData = new Array(
          'emp='+ $("#emp").val(), //build a post data structure
          'sdate='+ $("#sdate").val(),
          'tdate='+ $("#tdate").val(),
          'address='+ $("#address").val(),
          'city='+ $("#city").val(),
          'state='+ $("#state").val(),
          'zip='+ $("#zip").val(),
          'pos='+ $("#pos").val(),
          'sal='+ $("#sal").val(),
          'phone='+ $("#phone").val(),
          'sname='+ $("#sname").val(),
          'duties='+ $("#duties").val(),
          'reason='+ $("#leave").val()
        );
        alert(myData)
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "inc/functions.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"Data", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:myData, //Form variables
        success:function(data){
            alert('back')
         },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
        });
    });
```

it will display that it came back but of course the error is that the fields are null.
any help appreciated.
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still really teaching myself ajax, returning the data in the correct format was the original problem, turns out it was working as intended, however i didnt really know how to handle it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are sending data to the server is not correct. The better way to do it is to use form serialization:

```
$("#loginbtn").click(function () {

    //build a post data structure
    var myData = $('#login-form').serialize();
    alert(myData)
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "inc/functions.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType: "Data", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data: myData, //Form variables
        success: function (data) {
            alert('back');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

For this to work, make sure all you input fields have `name` attributes, like `emp`, `sdate`, etc. Then on server side you will be able to read POST parameters like this

```
$_POST['emp']
```

The problem with your approach is that when you provide just an array there is no keys corresponding to values, and that's why you can't read nothing in PHP.